# Angularjs - refresh `d3js` chart when data change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I created a `directive` for my `d3js` chart:

```
html:
<donuts-chart chart-data="mydonuts" ></donuts-chart>

directive:
.directive('donutsChart', function ($parse) {
var donutobject = {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false, 
    scope: {data: '=chartData'},
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.$watch('data', function(newVals, oldVals) {
        console.log('there is new data');
      }, true);

          };
    return donutobject;
   })
```

I add `scope.$watch` just to test if the data is updating. But it is not working. How can I get this to work? I need to update the chart whenever there is a new data.

Comment: can you check `scope.$watch('chartData'`

Comment: or what do you see in console when you do `scope.$watch(function(){ console.log(scope.chartData, scope.data);return scope.chartData}, function(newVals, oldVals) {})`

Comment: I do get`'there is new data'` when the `ui-view` first loaded. However when I add in new data, nothing happen.

Comment: what is this data that you are watching is it a array if yee then it should be $watchCollection..or can you make a fiddle for this...